# Hosting Multiple Drawings in one Visio vsd Diagram

Tags: database, microsoft-visio, diagrams, architecture

I'm using Visio 2007 and strawed creating some flowchart diagrams. One on each page. For the same project I would also like to create class and entity relational diagrams. Is it possible for me to have multiple drawing types in a single vsd?

I tried creating an ERD by adding the Entity Relational shapes to my palette, but when I dragged the entity shape unto the canvas I was not able to access the properties to add columns. Is there a way around this other than creating another vsd?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems the ERD shapes require that you use the template the shapes were made for.  That template probably contains some properties or even code that is required to use tools you described.  I'm pretty sure the templates that come with Visio don't contain their own code, so probably it's a matter of the custom properties/data on the template pages.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a built-in method in Visio for copying a whole page (just the shapes on a page), so theoretically you're stuck with multiple VSD files.  Unless, if your flowchart shapes work in any template you could create your drawings as ESD's and build your flowcharts in different pages.

Hopefully that helps answer your question.